# asp.net mvc web app is not running on defined port in IIS express 10.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am working on asp.net mvc web application project in visual studio 2015 with .NET framework 4.5. it was configured to run over ssl port 44302. i had to format my OS. After re-installing everything. it changed to run over other port. when i try to change port manually now it is not working. i re-installed iis express. deleted ssl and using netsh.

still can't able to make it work on port 44302. when i set this to port 44302. iis express does not start it. i am worried if i need to re-install OS or can i solve this. 
please have a look in picture>
[image]

Comment: Go to resource monitor -> Listening ports and find out which  process is using that port.

Comment: i checked listening ports but i don't find this port there. it's not running there. i am adding a snip as well.

Comment: Can you run Jexus Manager to collect more information? https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html and https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html and https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html The more you know of the project settings and your Windows configuration, the clearer what is the culprit.

Comment: i downloaded Jexus Manager. unfortunately it's not running in Win 10 prof.

Answer (score 1):

The "override application URL" checkbox isn't checked so the URL isn't being overridden.

Comment: i checked that box, still iis express is not able to run application on port 44302.

Comment: If you try to call the right URL in your browser, can you reach the website ?

Comment: yes, it's working on http and https both but not on port 44302. but i have to run this only on port 44302 which seems not running from iis express anymore.

Answer (score 1):

visual studio 2017 localhost didn't send any data under SSL.
I found that the proxy setting for localhost had been hi-jacked by a video downloader program. Went to network settings > proxy and turned it off. Suddenly working!!